# Searching multiple Item in one TextBox Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, search

First thanks in Advance for the help provided by this community
i have a problem where my client want to update records in database in one go.
so the solution was he delimit his object with "," in Excel then copy/past to a textBox, the thing
is the query works fine for a single records but for many its not working.

Code below
for the Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
```

namespace ctivation.Models {
public partial class BDD
{
[Required]
[StringLength(50)]
public string CODE { get; set; }

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string NOM { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public long TYPE{ get; set; }

    [Key]
   
    public Long NBR { get; set; }

    public bool STATUS { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string OBSERVATION { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? DATE_MAJ { get; set; }
}
```

}

Controler :

```
public ActionResult Index(string  search)
    {
        var query = _context.BDD.ToList();

        if (search == null)
            query = _context.Database.SqlQuery<BDD>("select * from [BDD] where CONVERT (varchar,[NBR])IN(@p0)", search).ToList();
        else
        {
            string x = addComa(search);
         
           query = _context.BDD.SqlQuery("select * from [BDD] where CONVERT (varchar,[NBR])IN (@search)", new SqlParameter("@search", x)).ToList();



        }


        return View(query);
       
        
    }
```

and the View

```
    @model IEnumerable<SimActivation.Models.BDD_ARPT>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<h2>Search</h2>



@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "BDD"))
{
    <b>@Html.TextBox("search") 
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit"value = "Search" /></b>
    }

... table code

what i want is something like that were the number's are multiple records in the Database [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL4hA.png

thanks again for the help
```

Comment: if `query = _context.Database.SqlQuery<BDD>("select * from [BDD] where CONVERT (varchar,[NBR])IN(@p0)", search).ToList();`  is working as expected, then you can use the same for other case also. I would suggest to save the query in string variable and then put a breakpoint and see what is its value. it will help you to check whether your query it right or wrong

Comment: The problem the query is fine but it wont show any records when clicking the search button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Linq to do it :

```
var values = search.Split(",");  
query = _context.BDD.Where(b => values.Contains(b.NBR)).ToList();
```

and don't forget to include `System.Linq` :

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: it Does work thank you very much although for values = search.Split(",");  it should be like this String [] x = search.Split(',') thanks again